# Calculator tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I was wondering, why is there a stackoverflow tag for TI-83 and TI-84, but there is no tag for the HP-48 or HP-49/50? I also found it odd that the 83 and 83+ are not separate. It would be better to have a 83 and 83+/84 tag, since the 84 is only a better 83+.  ([Source](http://www.ticalc.org/basics/calculators/): Ticalc.org, "The TI-84 Plus is an upgrade to the TI-83 Plus", "[TI 83 Plus] is the 'base model' of the highly popular 83/84 Plus series")

Comment: Tags are made when people use them. Apparently, people program on TIs more than HPs.

Answer (score 5):

People have to ask questions concerning them in order for there to be a tag for them. Tags aren't just "created." They can't exist without questions under them. If you think that 83 and 83+ need separated, then you need to provide evidence and prove that 83 and 83+ are different enough to warrant it, as well that there are enough questions to separate into each tag.

Comment: Looking at the two tags, there are only 4 questions tagged with [tag:ti-83], **all** of which are also tagged with [tag:ti-84], which has only 18 questions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to animuson's answer, TI still sells the 83 and 84, HP doesn't sell the 48 or 49 any more.  And I guess there's not the same user enthusiasm for the 50 as there was for the 41, 28, and 48...